# Render view on click event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is there a way so that the ItemViews contained in a CompositeView only render on say clicking a button?
I would like a change in the collection to update the Composite View's dom but each individual ItemView should not render until required.

Pardon me if I'm a little vague in my description but I have very limited knowledge of backbone and marionette.

Comment: would be great if you could put the code which u've done, and we continue from where you stuck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you well know, Marionette is eager to take your Composite (or Collection) View's children views and spawn them. That's why included in the Composite View `render` method is the `_renderChildren` process. Once invoked, there's really no way to *selectively* render children views.

But there's a back door that gets around rendering your entire collection. It's a simple as `initializing` your Composite View with an empty collection, like this

```
//Define MyCollection` and MyCompositieView and then...
var myCollection = new MyCollection(); // Construct an empty collection

var myCompositeView = new MyCompositeView({ collection: myCollection });
```

An "empty" Composite View will render its own template normally, and simply skip `_renderChildren`.

You can then wire an event to call `myCompositeView.collection.add(model)`. You'll notice that Marionette listens for an `add` event on your collection,

```
_initialEvents: function() {
  if (this.collection) {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this._onCollectionAdd);

    // Other _initialEvents methods...
  }
},
```

and `_onCollectionAdd` is responsible for rendering the added model:

```
_onCollectionAdd: function(child) {
  this.destroyEmptyView();
  var ChildView = this.getChildView(child);
  var index = this.collection.indexOf(child);
  this.addChild(child, ChildView, index);  // The rendering happens here
},
```

### Putting it all together

To make this work you'd have to have an array of your models inside your CompositeView, but outside that view's collection. I usually just wire up an `$.getJSON` (or any other AJAX method) to get the data and store it in a property of the View object. Say you do this on initialize:

```
initialize: function() {
  var that = this,
      dataUrl = "some/url";
  $.getJSON(dataUrl, function(data) {
    that.myModels = data;
  });
},
```

And, in your Composite View you'd probably have an event, say a click on an element of your Composite view:

```
events: {
  'click button': 'addChild'
}

addChild: function (event) {
  // functionality to identify which child to add to the collection
  this.collection.add(this.myModels[j]); // Where 'j' is the index the model you want lives in.
});
```

When `addChild` is called the collection adds the proper model, and Mariontte makes sure to render a child view populated with this model.

There variations on how to do this, and you don't have to have an event wired in your view. But I think I proved how you can have methods render independently. If you provide more information I can give you more ideas.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the crisp and concise description. Worked like a charm!

Comment: My pressure, glad it helped!